# Named accumulator in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

In scala spark it is possible to create a named accumulator which will display in the web ui by

```
val accum = sc.accumulator(0, "My Accumulator")
```

However the pyspark `sc.accumulator()` method has no name argument. Is it possible to create a named accumulator in pyspark which will display in the web ui?

Answer (score 5):

creating a named accumulator is not possible in pyspark. this issue has already been raised. you can track this thread https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-2868.

Answer (score 0):

If you're desperate enough, and you need to see the progress of your workers, you can use broadcast variables, as long as named accumulators are not yet available in python.

I'd recommend this solution only for testing.

Assuming you need to estimate a simple counter of records you've handled, all you have to do is output some information out of every worker:

```
# Get a spark context sc and read your data into and rdd (or DataFrame)
rows = sc.textFile("/path/to/data/sample_data.txt")
# broadcast an object defined like below
processor = spark.sparkContext.broadcast(Processor())
# Apply this lambda to your rdd
mapped = rows.map(lambda x: processor.value.process(x))
# Other transformations you need to do
sc.stop()

class Processor:
    def process(self, content):
        # either print some output to the screen
        print(content)
        
        # or write to a file
        # notice that you can't keep an open file as a class field
        # because broadcast variables need to be serializable
        with open('results.txt', 'a') as f:
            f.write(content + "\n")

        # or call an API to store and count the requests
        requests.get('https://some.external.api/' + content)

        return self.other_processing(content)
```

You can check the progress while your jobs are running by looking at the number of lines you've outputted to the screen, or the file, or using your API.

This solution has drawbacks:

- Opening and writing to a file for every item you have will drastically increase execution time
- Calling the API will also lower performance, maybe an async call can perform better

I've also tried setting a `self.counter = 0` into the Processor object, and each time the process() method is called I increase the counter by 1, and print it out. This doesn't affect performance at all, but you'll have a hard time figuring out what is being displayed on the screen because you'll probably be running it with all CPU cores and maybe in a cluster.